# How many screens do two R9 290 cards support when put in crossfire?

Tags: multiple-monitors, gpu, amd-radeon, crossfire

How many screens do two R9 290 cards support when put in crossfire?

I know nvidia has the limitation of only supporting two screens when in SLI mode, what's the maximum ATI supports when using crossfire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use the primary card while in crossfire mode. There have been special eyefinity cards with 6 outputs in the past (e.g. for the 7850), so if you really need to go 4+, you might want to wait for that.

Source: http://support.amd.com/en-us/search/faq/173 and using Crossfire on 2 7970 with 3 Displays and one TV myself.